# Extracting minimum and maximum from line number grep

Tags: bash

Currently, I have a command in a bash script that greps for a given string in a text file and prints the line numbers only using sed ...

```
grep -n "<string>" file.txt | sed -n 's/^\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
```

The grep could find multiple matches, and thus, print multiple line numbers.  From this command's output, I would like to extract the minimum and maximum values, and assign those to respective bash variables.  How could I best modify my existing command or add new commands to accomplish this?  If using awk or sed will be necessary, I have a preference of using sed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the minimum and maximum with this:

```
grep -n "<string>" input | sed -n -e 's/^\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' -e '1p;$p'
```

You can also read them into an array:

```
F=($(grep -n "<string>" input | sed -n -e 's/^\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' -e '1p;$p'))
echo ${F[0]} # min
echo ${F[1]} # max
```

Comment: Grep get's it's name from `sed -n g/re/p`. You should be able to combine everything into sed instead of piping the output of a grep into a sed.

Comment: But the line number thing complicates this. Looks like you need a sed-sed pipe to do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -n "<string>" file.txt | sed -n -e '1s/^\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p' -e '$s/^\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer works. I would ideally like to print out exclusively the min or exclusively the max. Is there a way for your command to only print the minimum or only the maximum? Or would you suggest the same solution that perreal has offered below?

Answer (score 1):

```
grep .... |awk -F: '!f{print $1;f=1} END{print $1}'
```

Comment: This might be a little easier to understand: `... | awk -F: 'NR==1{print $1} END{print $1}'`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers ha yes! I just thought about the boolean... "forgot"  `NR` is line number. :)

Comment: also `grep` is not needed! Built the grep in the awk. Save a process for the rainforests! ;)

Comment: @TrueY not 100% true. how do you know OP didn't write a Perl regex?

Comment: @Kent: See my example bellow. If `awk` is used, You do not need `grep` (or `sed`, or `wc` or alike...). But, of course You are right! `Grep` and `sed` uses older version of regex, so if You are bound to RE and You cannot convert to ERE then You have to used them. But this is very rare...

Comment: @Kent: I misinterpretered You comment! Yes, but if You want to use perl regex, use perl. :)

Comment: @TrueY I would learn perl if I have to. thanks for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it, since `grep -n 'pattern' file` prints output in the format `line number:line contents` ...

```
    minval=$(grep -n '<string>' input | cut -d':' -f1 | sort -n | head -1)
    maxval=$(grep -n '<string>' input | cut -d':' -f1 | sort -n | tail -1)
```

the `cut -d':' -f1` command splits the `grep` output around the colon and pulls out only the first field (the line numbers), `sort -n` sorts the numeric line numbers in ascending order (which they would already be in, but it's good practice to ensure it), then `head -1` and `tail -1` remove the first, and last value in the sorted list respectively, i.e. the minimum and maximum values and assign them to variables `$minval` and `$maxval` respectively.

Hope this helps!

Edit: Turns out you can't do it the way I had it originally, since echoing out a list of newline-separated values apparently concatenates them into one line.

Comment: I like this solution but it seems to be giving me an error: `head: cannot open '96' for reading: No such file or directory
head: cannot open '100' for reading: No such file or directory`.  Of course, the numbers are in the context of my input file but it doesn't seem to be liking `head` or `tail`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: It's also saying `tail: option used in invalid context -- 1`

Comment: Turns out you can't do it the way I had it originally (using that third variable) since when you echo it puts all the values on a single line (which means head and tail don't work properly).

The code up there should work fine now

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with one process. Like this:

```
awk '/expression/{if(!n)print NR;n=NR} END {print n}' file.txt
```

Then You can assign to an array (as perreal suggested). Or You can modify this script and assign to varables using eval

```
eval $(awk '/expression/{if(!n)print "A="NR;n=NR} END {print "B="n}' file.txt)
echo $A
echo $B
```

Output (`file.txt` contains three lines of `expression`)

```
1
3
```